# How to Check the App is running on Tablet or PC using C# code

Tags: winrt-async

I want to check the app is running on Tablet or PC using C# code in Windows 8 Metro Style apps

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: It can't be done.

You can have a tablet that doesn't run with a ARM processor, then it's basically a laptop, just in another form factor. The form factor is not something you check for using code. However you can still find the architecture and determine if you run ARM/x86/x64 checking out this [blogpost](http://attackpattern.com/2013/03/device-information-in-windows-8-store-apps/) - and then writing:

```
var cpu = await SystemInfoEstimate.GetProcessorArchitectureAsync();
```

You can also, in your project, set the CPU configuration - create separate ARM/x86/x64 configurations. And thereby create conditional builds of your application fitting each architecture.